# Undefined offset DatabaseLog->findCaller() (line 156 of D:\wamp\www\drupal7.24\includes\database\log.inc

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am working on a drupal project where i need to write cron that runs in 10 minuts and update database. I am using drupal 7.24 latest version.

I created a seperate PHP file and load drupal full bootstrap as

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT',getcwd());
chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT);
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Now i have written a select query using db_select() function and it gave following errors.

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in DatabaseLog->findCaller() (line 156 of D:\wamp\www\drupal-7.24\includes\database\log.inc).

I did not recognized how to resolved it. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Raj kishor

Answer (score 0):

I have created one file and i put at root directory and it worked for me . Please check below

```
echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']); // optional
require_once 'includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL); // load Drupal to use Drupal API

$users = db_select('users', 'u')
->fields('u', array('uid'))
->condition('u.status', 1, '=');
$users->innerJoin('users_roles', 'ur', 'u.uid = ur.uid');
$users = $users->execute();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->uid;

}
```